# Not able to access api gateway through user credentials

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-userpools

I have created an api gateway with AWS_IAM authentication. I need to access that api gateway so created one user with giving AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess policy to that user. 
but i am not able to call that api. Getting error as

"user arn:aws:iam::######:user/username is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:region:####:#####/stage/method/path"

Where as when i go to aws console and try to simulate that policy it is allowing me to invoke that api.

I tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXyATZctkmQ . But its not working. Please let me know if anyone has gone through it and tried something to solve this before. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the iam policy you attached to the user's role? Obfuscating the base path of the API of course

Comment: For now I have used aws AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess policy to the user. Its json summery is - { "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "execute-api:Invoke", "execute-api:ManageConnections" ], "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*" } ] }

Comment: How are you testing connecting with IAM credentials?

Comment: Could you try this?  { "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "execute-api:Invoke", "execute-api:ManageConnections" ], "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/*" } ] } (note the added slash and star at the end of resource)

Comment: I got the error...it was because of boundaries set to the user. And we are not able to create user without that boundaries. So can't perform execute-api.